# Collision detection in libgdx for triangles

Tags: java, libgdx, collision-detection

I am making a simple game with libgdx and wanted to add some simple collision detection. I already managed to express my player by using a simple rectangle:

> boundingBox = new Rectangle(x + 10, y + 10, 13, 21);

but my obstacles seem to be much more complicated.
They are supposed to be spikes over which the player can jump and have a triangle shape. They pretty much look like this: 
http://kayin.pyoko.org/iwbtg/forums/Smileys/iwbtg/spikes.gif

As far as I noticed there is no triangle shape in libgdx. I already tried using polygons but they seem far too complicated for my purposes.

Is there an easy way to implement an accurate hitbox for them?

Thanks in advance for reading my post : )

EDIT:
Thanks everyone for your responses, everything works fine now, besides drawing my polygons for testing purposes. When I call

> shapeRenderer.polygon(kid.getVertices());

it only draws my polygon in the top left corner, since it's defined as

> boundingBox2.setVertices(new float[] { 10, 10, 10, 31, 23, 31, 23, 10 });

But I move it around in the update method of my kid class by using

> boundingBox2.setPosition(position.x, position.y);

Is there a way to use that position change inside

> shapeRenderer.polygon(kid.getVertices()); ?

Anyways I really appreciate your help and after sorting out this problem I will close this thread : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Polygon of your rectangle and your triangle.
You can even create a custom polygon if you want to add more advanced shapes.

To convert from rectangle to polygon is very easy, i made a method some months ago

```
public static float[] rectangleToVertices(float x, float y, float width,
        float height) {
    float[] result = new float[8];
    result[0] = x;
    result[1] = y;

    result[2] = x + width;
    result[3] = y;

    result[4] = x + width;
    result[5] = y + height;
    result[6] = x;
    result[7] = y + height;

    return result;
}
```

The good thing about libGDX polygon class is that you can move your polygon or even rotate it, and get the transformed vertices!

Now you can use the Intersector class

```
public static boolean overlapConvexPolygons(Polygon p1,
                            Polygon p2)
Check whether specified convex polygons overlap.
Parameters:
p1 - The first polygon.
p2 - The second polygon.
Returns:
Whether polygons overlap.
```

For testing purposes, after you end your sprite batch do like this

```
batch.end(); // you end your spritebatch
renderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
renderer.begin(ShapeType.Line)
renderer.polygon(polygonname.getVertices());
renderer.end();
```

Now you will be able to see your polygon.

Comment: Do you know how I can draw my polygon for testing purposes? I tried this: <shapeRenderer.polygon(kid.getVertices());      However it only crashes my program with the following output: Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Must call begin(ShapeType.Line)
 at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer.polygon(ShapeRenderer.java:1030)
 at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer.polygon(ShapeRenderer.java:1023)

Comment: I also tried using the overlap method on two Polygon objects now: if(overlapConvexPolygons(boundingBox2, kid.getBoundingBox2())), but it says: The method overlapConvexPolygons(Polygon, Polygon) is undefined for the type Spike. (Spike is my class name) This is weird because I'm passing in two Polygon objects..

Comment: I've edited my answer. If you have more questions don't forget to ask, and also if my answer helped you don't forget to accept it and upvote it!

Comment: @user3501232 overlapConvexPolygons is a static method of the Intersector class, so you have to use Intersector.overlapConvexPolygons(...)